# Automake, special flags for tests

Tags: c, automake

I've got a software project that I've split in modules.  They are compiled individually and linked into a library or an executable.  Nothing new on the table:

```
$ cat src/Makefile.am
...
bin_PROGRAMS = foobar
foobar_SOURCES = foobar.c helper.c
...
```

Unit tests verify properties of individual files, such as the correctness of a particular function.  Let's suppose I want to test the correctness of `helper.c`, I don't need to link `foobar.c` in my unit test:

```
$ cat tests/Makefile.am
...
check_PROGRAMS = test_helper
test_helper_SOURCES = test_helper.c ../src/helper.c
...
```

I think it is common practice to enable a different set of flags when compiling a unit test.  For example, one could decide to introduce special consistency checks, perhaps computationally heavy, and to enable them only when the source code is compiled as part of a unit test.

```
$ cat tests/Makefile.am
...    
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DTESTING
check_PROGRAMS = test_helper
test_helper_SOURCES = test_helper.c ../src/helper.c
...
```

I've got a similar situation, and I realized that the `-DTESTING` definition is not honored if the `foobar` executable is compiled before `test_helper`.

This is obviously due to the fact that Automake finds `helper.o` already compiled when building the unit test.  It also means that compiling the unit test first might enable the afore mentioned extra code, and embed it into the `foobar` executable.

Is there a way to tell Automake that the provided files should be recompiled in the context of unit tests, so that the unit test and the binary don't use the same compiled object?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found a solution.

Quoting the Automake manual:

> 27.8 Per-Object Flags Emulation
>
> > One of my source files needs to be compiled with different flags. How do I do?
>
> Automake supports per-program and per-library compilation
>   flags (see Section 8.4 [Program and Library Variables], page 65, and
>   Section 27.6 [Flag Variables Ordering], page 145). With this you can
>   define compilation flags that apply to all files compiled for a
>   target.  For instance in
>
> ```
> bin_PROGRAMS = foo
> foo_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h bar.c bar.h main.c
> foo_CFLAGS = -some -flags
> ```
>
> `foo-foo.o`, `foo-bar.o`, and `foo-main.o` will all be compiled with `-some -flags`. (If you wonder about the names of these object files, see Section 27.7 [Renamed Objects], page 148.)